# My enhanced Auth dialog looks completely different from others

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog, authentication, facebook-authentication

my enhanced Auth dialog looks completely different from others. I would be very happy to have the same dialog like shown in your explanation. My one says: "Ok, Go to App" and doesn´t show my friends using the app. What can I do for that?

Best,
Max

Comment: show us a screenshot of your dialog, and one with the wanted look.

Comment: You may also have authenticated referrals enabled, and/or the app may be using timeline units

Answer (score 0):

It's the "Enhanced Auth Dialog". Deactivate it under Advanced.